# Div 100% width issue inside the frame

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have two divs (pink and grey) inside the main frame. Pink div has fixed width 1200px (which is dynamic and can be changed on every load to 1400px, 1800px, 2200px or whatever) whereas grey div has 100% width. When you scroll the frame to the right side, you will noticed gray bar is not coming 100% to the end of the page. Please guide me how can I make the grey bar 100% wide to the end of the page?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/r3C4B/1/

Below is my code:

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="header">Page Header</div>
    <div class="gray-bar">Edit | Delete</div>
</div>

.frame{overflow-x: scroll;}
.header{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:1200px;
    background:pink;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    }
.gray-bar{
    padding: 6px;
    width:100%;
    height: 20px;
    background:#e6e6e5;
    clear:both;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your header is too wide and stretching the whole frame. you have to either make your header 100% instead of a fixed 1200px or give your gray bar the same fixed width as header

Answer (score 0):

You tried to set width for header tag in pixel and gray tag in %.It wont work because in gray tag u mention it as 100% it take only visible part of window. if you want to keep both same width change width 100% or width 1200px.
refer

> ```
>   "http://jsfiddle.net/sidharthan_r/r3C4B/4/"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to add more markup to achieve this.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r3C4B/3/)

Wrap `.header` and `.gray-bar` in a container and change the width of the container instead of `.header`

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">Page Header</div>
        <div class="gray-bar">Edit | Delete</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.frame{overflow-x: scroll;}
.header{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;  /*  THIS BECOMES 100%  */
    background:pink;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    }
.gray-bar{
    padding: 6px;
    width:100%;
    height: 20px;
    background:#e6e6e5;
    clear:both;
    }
.wrapper {
    width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but can we use wrapper width 100% instead of 1200px? I need everything flexible. Please guide... Thanks